# Tools other than compass and straightedge

Tags: geometric-construction

What other mathematical construction tools or methods do exist apart from compass and straightedge?

I know of **[folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_paper_folding)** and **neusis** (incl. [tomahawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomahawk_(geometry))), also perhaps calipers (dividers) for [plastic ratio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsGUEj4w9Cc).

One question mentioned "3D ruler": [Are there numbers that we can't get with a usual compass and ruler, but can get with 3D compass and ruler?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920780/are-there-numbers-that-we-cant-get-with-a-usual-compass-and-ruler-but-can-get)

Is there any other? Perhaps some classification of them?

I'm looking for simple methods, [nothing complicated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125758/did-anyone-ever-build-a-mechanical-device-to-take-fifth-roots-or-solve-general).

Comment: Notice that the classical tool is not a ruler but a straightedge. I’ve been told that with a straightedge marked with two distinguished points, you can, for instance, trisect an angle.

Comment: @Lubin, see Arthur Baragar, Constructions using a compass and twice-notched straightedge, http://baragar.faculty.unlv.edu/papers/TwiceNotch.pdf

Answer (score 2):

One such tool is the [ellipsograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trammel_of_Archimedes) (trammel of Archimedes). It's related to the [Tusi couple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tusi_couple). Here is a demonstration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Fn-26Jmi5E

A related toy is the [spirograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirograph).

Another tool that uses mechanical links is the [pantograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantograph). It's used for copying and scaling.

The [harmonograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonograph) employs *pendulums* to draw curves.

Answer (score 1):

I very much enjoyed David Richeson's *Tales of Impossibility* ([MAA review link](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/tales-of-impossibility-the-2000-year-quest-to-solve-the-mathematical-problems-of-antiquity)), which is a history of the famous geometrical problems of antiquity including [angle trisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection) and [circle squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_circle).

In interstitials between chapters on the book Richeson reviews other tools to be added to the geometer's toolkit in addition to the neusis, including:

- the scissors mentioned by the OP,
- the [tomahawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomahawk_(geometry)) mentioned by the OP,
- the [mesolabe](https://kotsanas.com/gb/exh.php?exhibit=2401003) of Eratosthenes, and
- a [carpenter's square](https://kotsanas.com/gb/exh.php?exhibit=2401003).

Richeson also discusses other interesting construction techniques in addition to origami, such as with toothpick geometry.  I learned of an interesting angle trisection with toothpicks, discovered by the author of the children's book [Harold and the Purple Crayon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harold_and_the_Purple_Crayon).